# conda environment: install only new or upgraded packages in an environment?

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda

I am trying to create a new conda environment for my project on a server.  The problem is I have only 2GB in my home directory, of which roughly 1GB would be used for the conda environment.  Since my project depends on a lot of packages, which would sum up to over 2GB, and many of them (e.g. numpy/scipy/etc) have already been installed in the root environment (which I cannot modify without root permission).  I wonder if it is possible to install only packages that are not available in root environment or those with different versions in root environment so that I could possibly save a lot of space?

Thank you!

Comment: By default, I'm pretty sure that conda symlinks packages from the directory where they get unzipped. So this should "just work"...

Comment: @darthbith "conda create -n newroot --clone root" still downloads packages and still counts in my storage quota.  Is there any other way to actually create "soft link"?

Comment: Sorry, not sure... It's possible the administrators have cleaned out the cache of the root environment to save space there, causing packages to be re-downloaded.